# Searching for list of values in a Django JSONField

Tags: django, django-1.9, django-jsonfield

So I've got this `model` with this `JSONField` -

```
class Details(models.Model):
    ref_det = JSONField(null=True, default=dict())
```

`ref_det` stores values in this format

```
{'user_id': '2231', 'org_id': 'qpdkm12'}
```

Each object of the model has its `ref_det` as a dictionary of just those two values.

Now I have this list of user IDs - `user_ids` - and I want to get those objects from the model where the `user_id` key in its `ref_det` field contains any of those `user_id` in the `user_ids` list.

So if I have `user_ids = ['2231', '973','431']`, I should get those `Details` objects whose `ref_det` has its `user_id` as any of the 3 values in the list.

I tried looking up through `contains`, but I think that supports lookups of only a single value and not a list.

I think `__values__contains` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield) is appropriate for this usecase, but then again, I don't have an `HStoreField`.

Does anyone know how I can get through this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is a jsonfield the right choice here ? Since "Each object of the model has its ref_det as a dictionary of just those two values", a proper relational model would be much simpler to use and probably perform better.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - I agree, but the JSONField had been months earlier and is already being used in many places. So I thought it's better to work around it, rather than create a new model.

Comment: I'm not talking about "creating a new model" but about modifying the existing one, which can be done easily using migrations. This of course requires changes to the client code (code using this model) but if it's known that you will always have those two keys and only those two keys in the jsonfield then fixing a wrong design is better than "working around" it, even if it requires a bit more work now (hint: it will certainly save time in the future). Just my 2 cents...

Comment: You're right. That's certainly better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Django 1.10 or upper:

You can try like this:

```
 Details.objects.filter(ref_det__user_id__in=['2231', '973','431'])
```

#### Django 1.9:

You can try like this:

```
 list(filter(lambda x: x.ref_det.get('user_id') in ['2231', '973','431'], Details.objects.all()))  # it will return a list not queryset
```

FYI: I tried this with `Django 1.10.8`, but I think, you can do lookup operations like `contains`, `in`, `isnull` inside JSONField([reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#key-index-and-path-lookups)).

Comment: You are right, this solution does not work for Django 1.9. Let me see if there is other ways to do that

Comment: So what if `ref_det` is a list of dictionaries, and you want to search for the user IDs in any of the dictionaries in the lists from the queryset? Is that possible?